Proving set all of functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is uncountable
I know this is a duplicate question, but I could not find a solution similar to my own on this website, so I am making a post to see potential errors in it. My proof is generally as follows:

Let S = {f | f : N->N} and assume S is countable
Every f in S can be defined as a bit string, where the nth digit (starting at 0) of the bitstring is 1 if f maps to n, and 0 if not. For example: if f was defined by f(0) = 1, f(1) DNE, f(2) = 0, and f(3) = 9, f's bitstring would be 1011.
Since S is countable by assumption, each f in S can be ordered in some way such that every f is counted once. Let g(n) denote the bit string for the nth f in S
Then every g and it's corresponding nth digit could be represented in a table. The rows would be each g (0th, 1st, 2nd, ...), and the columns would be the nth digit of the bitstring for every g.
Now, use Cantor's Diagonalization to show that a unique g can be made, and thus a unique f that is not present in the table. This contracts the assumption that S is countable, thus it is not.

I know that this bitstring method is not entirely correct (as two fs could share the same bitstring despite being unequal), but I was wondering how critical that error is. I had to think of it on the spot for an exam. After the exam, I realized it would be much easier to simply write the table where the rows were all of the fs and the columns were the natural numbers, with the (x,y)th entry being yth f's value at x.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

What is DNE? Also, you defined $f$ only for $0$, $2$ and $3$.

I don't think thins works.  Not only can two different functions be mapped to the same bitstring, but an uncountably inifinite number of functions.  EVERY function without a fixed point gets mapped to $00000.....$.  For ever zero in the $n$th position there are an infinite number of values $f(n) \ne n$ can be.  So if a bitstring has an infinite number of $0$s there are $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ possible functions this can represent.  (Alson in your example you represent a function having a finite bitstring. All function have to have infinite bitstrings.)

Oh... you meant the $n$th terms is one if $f(n)$ exists.  Well, as $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ then all numbers are mapped (that's what a function is) so every functions bitstring is $111111.....$ and you list has only one element on it.  [For what it's worth the traditional way would be to list functions as ... functions (no need to turn them into anything else)  Make a now function $g$ by letting $g(n)$ be anything other than what the $n$th function maps $n$ to (for example $1+$ whatever then $n$th function maps $n$ to)]

I assume "DNE" stands for "Does Not Exist". It must be, right? I think you are confused, functions are defined for all arguments. That's a major mistake, because every function has exactly one same representation with this construction: $1111\cdots$.
It could work for the set of all partial functions, but then you would still need to prove the claim for the set of all non-partial functions, because of the next paragraph:
Secondly, what exactly is a (bit) string? And an infinite one in your case? It's a different word for a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to something, in your case $\{0,1\}$. So you've converted one set of functions to another one. Perhaps simpler, but it doesn't really matter. Because you didn't actually provide a proof for neither. You've only increased complexity of the reasoning IMO.
Third, I'm not sure why you need "tables". I understand the intuition behind it, but formality is a different thing. The diagonalization argument goes like this: say all those functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ can be arranged into $(f_n)$ sequence. Then we define $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ via $g(n)=f_n(n)+1$ or whatever formula such that $g(n)\neq f_n(n)$. Which literally means that $g\neq f_n$, regardless of $n$, leading to a contradiction. And that's how formally this should be presented.
I hope you will pass the exam. If not, don't worry. I'm sure you will be prepared next time. :)
